# Need one set of tabs to activate two containers

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use tabs to activate both a Coda slider in the left column and tabbed content in the center of the page. The slider is activated but the tabs are not.

Here's the jquery from the top of the page:

```
$(".tab_content").hide();
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("current_page_item").show();
$(".tab_content:first").show();
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("current_page_item");
    $(this).addClass("current_page_item");
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).find('id').attr('a');
    //alert(activeTab);
    $(activeTab).show('slow'); 
    return false;
}
```

I've tried both  .attr('a'); and .attr('id');  but only the slider fires, the tab container goes blank.

I'm new at this and just trying to learn javascript and jquery. I have been reading on a lot of forums but can't find anyone trying to activate two tab or slider containers with only a single set of tabs.

Thanks much for any help.

```
<div id="menu"> 
    <ul class="tabs"> 
       <li><a href="#0" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" id="tab0">Why Us?</a></li>     
       <li><a href="#1" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" id="tab1">CCW Class</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#2" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" id="tab2">Beginner</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#3" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" id="tab3">Advanced</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML as well?

Comment: I do have a tabs.js and 3 other jquery.js documents included with coda slider. The html follows. Thanks for the help.
'code'<div id="menu">
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#0" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" id="tab0">Why Us?</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#1" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" id="tab1">CCW Class</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" id="tab2">Beginner</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" id="tab3">Advanced</a></li>
</ul> 'code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working to fire both the coda slider and change the tab container by clicking a tab.
`

```
            });
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide al content
            $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("current_page_item").show();//Activate first tab
            $(".tab_content:first").show();//Show first tab content
            //On Click Event
            $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
                $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("current_page_item");
                $(this).addClass("current_page_item");

                $(".tab_content").hide(); //hide all content tabs
                var activeTab = $(this).data('getTab'); //get the html5 data element
                //var selectTab = "#"+activeTab;
                //alert(activeTab); //debugging
                //$(activeTab).show('slow'); 
                $(activeTab).fadeIn();
                return false;

            });


<ul class="tabs">
    <li data-getTab="#content0"><a href="#1" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" >Why Us?</a></li>
    <li data-getTab="#content1"><a href="#1" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" >CCWClass</a></li>
    <li data-getTab="#content2"><a href="#2" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" >Beginner</a></li>
    <li data-getTab="#content3"><a href="#3" class="xtrig" rel="coda-slider-1" >Advanced</a></li>
```

`

It changes up to nine tab containers with the corresponding coda slider panels in the left column.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

`var activeTab = $(this).find('id').attr('a');` seems have to be `var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
var activeTab = $(this).find('id').attr('a');
```

This looks for an "a" attribute of and element of tag "id". There is no `<id a='something'></id>` tag in HTML. I assume you're trying to find the A tag within "this":

```
var activeTab = $(this).find('a')
```

In this line:

```
$(activeTab).show('slow');
```

jQuery looks for an OBJECT reference, so you don't need to get the ID of an object, just the object itself, which is why you don't need the ID in `$(this).find('a')`

Also,

```
return false;
```

If you're not calling the function from somewhere else that is looking for a returned value, there is no point in returning a value. Just delete it.

Comment: The return false is useful for stopping propogation and default behaviour. Although I would use the methods on the event object passed to the function instead.

Comment: I added tabs.js to the website when I found tabs I could use. Then I found the slider and added 3 other .js documents that I got with it. I thought it would work well if the left column info could change to match each tab of the page. My original page was a mile long and I am hoping to make it more readable. it's at [link](http://s314373879.onlinehome.us/stlccw.com) but not live yet as I'm still testing and tuning.